# IOS Custom View or Navigation Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to IOS Swift development. I have a navigation bar design which includes, increasing the height (thus increased text size with custom colors), custom UIButton for closing (instead of the usual back button)
and title at the left side (instead of center)

Basically a lot of customization to do. My question is, is it okay to do a custom UIView to act as a navigation bar or should I push through with a NavigationController and just customize it via code?

Thank you.

Comment: IMO, If you have buttons and images on the navigation bar then it is always good to have a custom view as a navigation bar, you could customise it as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the navigation bar offer the push navigation through different view controllers in a smarter way, it stacking all the view controllers pushed and it offers some useful features; for example pushing another view controller from storyboard you don't have the need to set the back button and you can come back to the main controller in a simple way.

You can set a custom image for left/right button, set custom fonts and also change the height without big problems; I suggest to keep the navigation bar and evaluate, you should discover in a short time if a nav bar is enough for your needs.

Comment: what do you think about hiding the navigation bar instead while still using the navigation controller and using a custom view? I got the results I was looking for without the extra code. Wondering though if this has major issues?